# PHP replace sub string with the value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

I have a text say:

```
$text = "An Elephant is an Elephant but an Elephant is not an Elephant"
```

And I have an array say:

```
$array = array("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eight", "Ninth");
```

In the text you can see there are many occurrences of "Elephant". What I want to do is I want to replace the occurrences of Elephant with unique values from the array and the result should be something like this:

```
$result = "An Fifth is an Seventh but an First is not an Fourth"
```

I have tried this so far :

```
$arr = array("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eight", "Ninth");
$text = "an elephant is an elephant but an elephant is not an elephant";
$array = explode(" ", $text);
$new_arr = array_diff($array, array("elephant"));
$text = implode(" ".$arr[array_rand($arr)]." ", $new_arr);
echo $text;
```

It outputs something like this:

```
an First is First an First but First an First is First not First an
```

How can I get like this?

```
An Fifth is an Seventh but an First is not an Fourth
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

With [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) you can then simply use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to always replace it with a random value out of your array.

```
<?php

    $arr = array("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eight", "Ninth");
    $text = "an elephant is an elephant but an elephant is not an elephant";

    echo $newText = preg_replace_callback("/\belephant\b/", function($m)use($arr){
        return $arr[array_rand($arr)];
    }, $text);

?>
```

possible output:

```
an Seventh is an Third but an First is not an Ninth
```

Comment: You Sir. Saved my day. That is what I exactly wanted. Thank You So much.

Comment: one last thing. Can you please tell me if the text contains "~hic~" instead of "elephant". Then how could I replace "~hic~" ?

Comment: @Illusion Just replace the regex: `/\belephant\b/` with `/~hic~/`

Answer (score 5):

Here, why don't you try this?

```
$arr = array("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eight", "Ninth");
$arrlength = count($arr);
$text = "an elephant is an elephant but an elephant is not an elephant";
$array = explode(" ", $text);
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    if ($array[$i]=="elephant")
    {
        $random_key = array_rand($arr, $arrlength);
        $array[$i] = $arr[$random_key[rand(0, $arrlength-1)]];
    }
}
$text = implode(" ", $array);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation to the answer of Rizier123, so you never have the same replacement. (Watch out you don't need to replace more items than the number of items you have in your array)

```
$arr = array("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eight", "Ninth");
$text = "an elephant is an elephant but an elephant is not an elephant";

echo $newText = preg_replace_callback("/\belephant\b/", function($m)use(&$arr){
  $item = array_rand($arr);  
  $return = $arr[$item];
  unset($arr[$item]);
  return $return;
}, $text);
```

Comment: Cool.. But one last thing. Can you please tell me if the text contains "~hic~" instead of "elephant". Then how could I replace "~hic~" ?